# How to calculate 1-CDF in R and plot it?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ecdf

I want to plot the 1-CDF in R

I am using the ggplot stat_ecdf

```
g1=ggplot() +
  stat_ecdf(data=data_ploting, aes(x, colour=ggg), alpha=0.8, geom= "smooth", pad = FALSE) +
  theme_test ()
```

Comment: What exactly is the "1-CDF"? Where is this defined? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Maybe you want `aes(x, y=1-stat(y), colour=ggg)`?

Comment: What I mean is to compute the 1-F(x) where F(x) is the empirical CDF P(X<=x) , and then plot it

Comment: Thanks for the explanation that you seek $1-F(x)$. I have edited my answer to show how this is done. Do not forget to mark the answer as accepted, if it actually solves your problem, so that the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 2):

The base R function `ecdf` returns a function that you can use in new expressions, including subtracting it from one. You can therefore also use the usual methods for plotting $1-F(x)$. Example:

```
x <- sort(iris$Sepal.Length)
cdf <- ecdf(x)
plot(x, 1 - cdf(x), type="s")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `?stat_ecdf` help page shows that there is a "Computed variable" `y` which holds the calculated CDF value. You can get at that value using `stat()` and then transform it however you like. So, for example, this should work

```
ggplot(data_ploting) +
  aes(x = x, y = 1-stat(y), colour=ggg) + 
  stat_ecdf(alpha=0.8, geom = "smooth", pad = FALSE)
```